# Reading a Maildir with Gnus

Tags: gnus, email

I have a directory `~/mail` containing directories and Maildirs.

I was hoping I might read messages contained in it by evaluating

```el
(setq gnus-select-method '(nnnil "")
      gnus-secondary-select-methods
      '((nnmaildir "private" (directory "~/mail"))))
```

and `M-x gnus`.  But I see only an empty buffer.  How do I find my messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select methods tell Gnus where to find your Maildir, but not which "groups" to subscribe to. See [`(gnus) Finding the News`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Finding-the-News.html), one of the first sections of the Gnus manual:

```
First of all, you should know that there is a special buffer called
‘*Server*’ that lists all the servers Gnus knows about.  You can press
‘^’ from the Group buffer to see it.  In the Server buffer, you can
press ‘<RET>’ on a defined server to see all the groups it serves
(subscribed or not!).  You can also add or delete servers, edit a
foreign server’s definition, agentize or de-agentize a server, and do
many other neat things.  See Server Buffer.  See Foreign Groups.
See Agent Basics.
```

Though it's possible to subscribe to groups from the Group buffer, I find it easier to go through the Server buffer as described above.

So, from the Group buffer (the one that you're greeted by when you start Gnus) press <kbd>^</kbd> to get to the Server buffer. Once there, select the relevant Maildir server by pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> with point on it. Then you can subscribe to any number of groups by pressing <kbd>u</kbd> with point on them. See [`(gnus) Browse Foreign Server`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Browse-Foreign-Server.html):

```
‘u’
     Unsubscribe to the current group, or, as will be the case here,
     subscribe to it (‘gnus-browse-unsubscribe-current-group’).  You can
     affect the way the new group is entered into the Group buffer using
     the variable ‘gnus-browse-subscribe-newsgroup-method’.  See *note
     Subscription Methods for available options.
```

Pressing <kbd>q</kbd> twice will exit the group browsing and Server buffers and you should be back in the Group buffer with your new group subscriptions visible.

Comment: thanks!  but after i press RET on something in the server buffer i see only an empty buffer.

Comment: @Toothrot That means you haven't configured the `nnmaildir` select method correctly, and/or the Maildir is in a format that Gnus doesn't understand.

Comment: @Toothrot Try setting `gnus-verbose` and `gnus-verbose-backends` to `10` in case anything interesting gets printed.

Comment: thanks, it eventually worked.  i suspect gnus only recognizes directories containing maildirs, not directories containing directories containing maildirs.

Comment: @Toothrot Yes, I think that's right. Though you might be able to get something to work using some of `nnmaildir`'s virtual server settings; I don't know and I haven't tried. See [`(gnus) Maildir`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Maildir.html).